# Eclipse process launch

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

How can I get the process of a launched java application inside of a plugin? I am using:

```
DebugUITools.launch();
```

to launch the application. I have tried to use:

```
IProcess cur = DebugUITools.getCurrentProcess();
```

but it returns null at the beginning of the application launch.

Actually, my aim is to read from the console of the running application and by having the current process I tried to call:

```
DebugUITools.getConsole(IProcess process);
```

which returns the console. The Q now is how to read from this console programmatically.

Comment: You should provide some code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `launch()`, call `buildAndLaunch()`, which gives you the `ILaunch` back. You can ask the `ILaunch` for `IProcess` objects.

Comment: sorry i am  new here.I clicked "was this helpful" and said yes but dont know how to accept it as a solution.If you can help me to find, i will do it with pleasure.Thanks again.